# Public Key Auth to GCP VM no longer working

Tags: ssh, authentication

I have 3 Google VMs that I cannot ssh to. It used to work but has stopped and I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

I have confirmed permissions for .ssh and keys on both machines.
The keys were added via the GCP interface and verified in authorized_hosts

On the client side this is the debug info I get

```bsh
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/XXXX/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/XXXX/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from XX.XX.XX.XX
debug1: Host 'XX.XX.XX.XX' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/XXXX/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /home/XXXX/.ssh/id_rsa2 (0x7fffd51f62c0), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 1
Received disconnect from XX.XX.XX.XX port 22:2: Connection blocked because server only allows public key authentication. Please contact your network administrator.
```

Watching the auth.log on the server I get: 
Aug  9 20:48:31 XXXX sshd[18975]: Connection closed by authenticating user XXXX XX.XX.XX.XX port 57813 [preauth]

So it appears like the 2 machines are pointing the finger at one another and saying "They did it"

This is my config file:

```bsh
Host XXXX
        User XXXX
        HostName XX.XX.XX.XX
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa2
        ServerAliveInterval 120
        ServerAliveCountMax 30
```

I'm out of ideas, anyone help please?

Comment: Solved. Just needed to restart the ssh service on the client side. I R Dumb